# calling android contacts application (by an intent ) inside an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

How to call Android contacts app inside an activity. The activity may contains other controls like button, but somewhere (inside the same activity) it displays the contacts app so that i can perform certain actions like add, view, edit etc. By actions, i mean the actions that Android contacts app provides. Following code calls android contacts app as an intent:

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.contacts", "com.android.contacts.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity"));
    i.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work like this. You can not add another app inside your app. You can use **Content Providers** for app functionality with contacts (e.g. to add/edit/remove contacts progmatically). or use intents with action `View`, `Edit` or `Pick` to handle the contact inside the contact application itself.

Comment: You are welcome @user3124780. If you see this as your answer, please mark it as the correct answer by checking the mark below the number in left of my answer.